# Installing WebSphere Process Server, Enterprise Service Bus, Message Broker, Service Registry and Repository

Tags: installation, ibm, websphere

I have got a Lab with 4 systems, each with 4 GB of RAM and I want to setup the following tools on the same. What is the best way to do the same?

1. IBM WebSphere Process Server 7
2. IBM WebSphere Enterprise Service Bus 7
3. IBM WebSphere Message Broker 7
4. IBM WebSphere Service Registry and Repository 7

I am very new to all these tools, but I know what each one does.

This lab will be used as a Development environment.

Any guidelines or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: All machines are on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, no one will write you here how to do this - this is rather wide topic, so that would take a lot of place;) There is only one way - assuming that you are not going to spend a lot of money for training - go to the IBM's infocenter and read manuals. Sorry, i know it's not something you wanted to hear, but this is how it is.